# Mongo Database, SELECT * WHERE id = 3 AND id = 4

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I have a MongoDB and I want to get two records or more records and put this in a map.
The code below works ok if I have just one `query.put(ïd", "7");` but it doesn't work if I put two or more in like in the code below.

```
    Map<Object,Object> map= new HashMap<Object,Object>();
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("Members");
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("id", "7");
    query.put("id", "3");
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
    DBObject one;
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        one = cursor.next();
        map.put(one.get("id"),one.get("name"));
    }
```

How would I get would I get two or more records in the map?
For SQL the equivalent would be `SELCT * FROM Member WHERE id = 7 AND id = 3`

Even more perfect would be if I could give a list as a query, not sure if this is possible.

Comment: A post with either id 7 and id 3? You mean a post should have either id 3 **or** id 7, not both.

Comment: Judging from your last sentence, I think the SQL you meant to post was `SELECT * FROM Member WHERE id IN ( 7, 3 )`.  Please edit question to use the correct equivalent SQL i.e. something that would actually return some rows.

Comment: In that `query.put` statement, did you copy/paste that?  Is that supposed to a standard `i` in `id`?  And shouldn't the `id` have both an opening & closing "?  Please copy/paste these things, instead of typing 'something like' what is in the code.

Comment: in the result i want two records, where the id = 3 and where the id = 4

Comment: @Marc: The terminology is "or," not "and." You want to retrieve records where the `id` is 3 **or** 7. Consider what you would mean if you said you wanted to retrieve record with the `id` 3 and the `name` "foo". You'd mean only the records where *both* of those were true, right? So no record could possibly match "where `id` is 3 and 7" (unless `id` is some kind of multi-value field or something).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want the [`$in` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/OR+operations+in+query+expressions), something like:

```
Map<Object,Object> map= new HashMap<Object,Object>();
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("Members");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("id", new BasicDBObject("$in", new Integer[] {3, 7}));
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);
DBObject one;
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    one = cursor.next();
    map.put(one.get("id"),one.get("name"));
}
```

...assuming the values are `Integer`s. I think both arrays and `BasicDBList` instances are supported.